# Change WebView font using CSS; font file in asset folder. (problem)

Tags: android, font-face, android-2.2-froyo

I want to change WebView font. There are 2 files in "assets" folder. They are:

assets/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf  and

assets/css/result.css

I searched some answers on StackOverflow and find out a solution but it doesn't work. The result.css loads DejaVuSans.ttf using @font-face directive. Then it is included in < link > tag of data which is passed to WebView::loadDataWithBaseURL (The code is below). **The problem is CSS styles works (the text is red) but the font doesn't**. Square characters appears when I show phonetic symbols (/'pə:sn/).

```
String resultText = "<html><head>";
resultText += "<link href=\"css/result.css\"" + " rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />";
resultText += "<style>" + "@font-face { font-family: \"DejaVuSans\"; " + "" +
"src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'); }</style>";
resultText += "</head>";
resultText += "<body><p>" + text + "</p>" + "</body></html>";
resultView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", resultText, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

result.css:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: "DejaVuSans"; 
    /*src: url('fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'); also not work*/ 
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf');
}

body {
    color: red;
}
```

The System.out.println(resultText) is:

```
   <html><head><link href="css/result.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><style>@font-face { font-family: "DejaVuSans"; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'); }</style></head><body><p>person /'pə:sn/</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was solved. I didn't add "font-family" to body selector and font url must be file:///android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf".

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'DejaVuSans'; 
    /* src: url('DejaVuSans.ttf'); This doesn't work */
    /* src: url('fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'); Neither is this */
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'); /* but this does */
}

body {
    font-family: 'DejaVuSans';
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I working on windows. How you came to know the "font-family"?

Comment: I have same problem but font still wont load. I write whole text file and typeface on a html file that loads to the web view.

Answer (score 4):

Known bug on 2.0 and 2.1 :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4448

For 2.2 :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName';
    src: url('filefont.ttf'); // with no "fonts/"
}
```

Comment: I used the tag "android-2.2". That bug is of 2.0. It was fixed in 2.2.

Comment: It doesn't work. My font file is in assets/fonts folder. I tried to copy it to assets/ but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

I used cufon replacement for devices that didn't support my local font face.
I wrote a javascript function to determine whether cufon is required

```
requiresCufon : function(){
    var version = window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android\s+([\d\.]+)/);
    var MINIMUM_OS_FONTFACE = 2.2;
    if(typeof version != 'undefined'){
        //strip non digits
        version = version[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
        //if version is less than required for @font-face then cufon
        if(parseFloat(version) < MINIMUM_OS_FONTFACE)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
},
```