# How to refer to files in asset folder from outside html

Tags: android, html, fonts, webview

This problem seems familiar but it's not! I have a webpage on a web server and a `webview` in Android application that loads the webpage. And instead of loading some font from the Internet (or website), i want to load fonts directly from  asset folder of Android device (to save data and faster). What i have done is to embed this code in the website with the hope it can use the font in Android asset folder instead:

```
@font-face { 
font-family: 'DejaVuSans'; 
src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'); /* but this does not work*/
}

body {
  font-family: 'DejaVuSans';
  color: red;
}
```

(link [Change WebView font using CSS; font file in asset folder. (problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724653/change-webview-font-using-css-font-file-in-asset-folder-problem))

I currently test with android 4.+. Can anyone have the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`file:` urls retrieve files from within one's own computer. For websites you should use relative or absolute urls. Here's a relative url example:

```
src: url('android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf');
```

Here's a absolute url example:

```
src: url('http://www.example.com/android_asset/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf');
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is how to load a font from local Android device. I don't want to load it from web server or any other resource from the Internet.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung then use relative urls. Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung I've also had issues with font-face rules for Android in the past. I would advice using Google Fonts or a similar service if possible otherwise make sure you have the proper font-face declaration.